# How to create a custom view storyboard outlet from a custom tableView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, customization, custom-view

I am trying to create a custom view in a custom tableviewcell. But I couldn't see any results.

```
//-- This is the custom tableview cell where I created custom view outlet and mentioned custom view class when creating outlet from tableviewcell.

class NetworkAccessByLocationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var chartView: MyCustomView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
 }

//--This is my custom View where I have code customized for view.


class MyCustomView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
           super.init(frame: frame)
           setup()
       }

       required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           super.init(coder: aDecoder)
           setup()
       }
    
        func setup() {
        //I have something here
        }

        func createBezierPath() -> UIBezierPath {
         //I have some code here
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you please describe the issue you're having in more detail?

Comment: When you say "couldn't see any results", is it that the `MyCustomView` is not being displayed or you're unable to link the `chartView` `IBOutlet` on `NetworkAccessByLocationTableViewCell`. Also, are you using dynamic prototype cells?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what your exact problem is but in order to use a custom UIView that is accessible in interface Builder, you need to create a IBDesignable view. Also since your's custom view doesn't contain xib, why don't you simply create an instance of your custom view in your cell and add anchor to it programmatically

```
let chartView = MyCustomView()
self.addSubview(chartView)
```

Then give the anchor your want to give in the custom cell for your chartView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       setupView()
       
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       setupView()
    
   }

   private func setupView() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: MyCustomView.self)
        if let view = UINib(nibName: <Name of MyCustomView's Xib file>, bundle: bundle).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView {
            view.frame = bounds
            view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
            addSubview(view)
        }
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
    //I have something here
    }

    func createBezierPath() -> UIBezierPath {
     //I have some code here
    }
```

}